# HazelCast over HTTP (or running on Google AppEngine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, hazelcast

From the wiki HazelCast works like:

```
 After discovery, node communication is only TCP/IP using Java NIO.
```

Is there a feasibility to have `HazelCast` to work over HTTP? So it can work with PaaS like Google AppEngine that only provides access to HTTP resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hazelcast provides REST interface. You can access `map` and `queue` using http protocol.

For example;

```
HTTP GET http://10.20.17.1:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/stocks/key1
```

means

```
IMap map = HazelcastInstance.getMap("stocks");
map.get("key1");
```

OR

```
HTTP POST http://10.20.17.1:5701/hazelcast/rest/maps/stocks/key1 <CONTENT>
```

means

```
IMap map = HazelcastInstance.getMap("stocks");
map.put("key1", <CONTENT>);
```

For more info see [Hazelcast documentation](http://hazelcast.com/docs/latest/manual/multi_html/ch15s03.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, its great that Hazelcast have a rest api, however, what I mean is that I can include Hazelcast in my AppEngine project, just like how we use it with a web application (like JSP or Servlet) deployed in Tomcat